# Is it possible to correct javascript within IE developer tools?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

As we hit `F12` we get to the IE developer tools starting from IE 8 .

It is very useful but i was not able to correct the code within this debugger .

Is there any way i could correct the script right in the debugger ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about IE8, but you can edit the code in other modern browsers, but it's for that local session only, changes will be lost once the page posts back

Answer (score 1):

When you could do it, everybody else could do it as well. As long your browser has no permission to access the server (e.g. with ftp or ssh) you can just change the behaviour of "your" displayed version like fnostro said before.